# How to display text of selectedOptions from multiselect list of array of objects in knockout.js

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a model like this

```
function SearchFilterOption(data){
    var self    =   this
    self.List           =   ko.observableArray([])
    self.SelectedOptions    =   ko.observable(0)
    self.SelectedOptionText     =   ko.computed(function(){
        return self.SelectedOptions()
    })
}
```

And here is binding

```
<select multiple="multiple"
    data-bind="
        options:List,
        optionsText:"Description",
        optionsValue:"Value",
        optionsCaption:"---",
        value:0,
        selectedOptions:SelectedOptions"
></select>
```

And here is json of list.

```
"Countries": [
            {"Value": 1,"Description": "United States"}, 
            {"Value": 2,"Description": "Canada"},
            {"Value": 3,"Description": "United Kingdom"},
            {"Value": 4,"Description": "Pakistan"},
            {"Value": 5,"Description": "India"}
]
```

Now when i select multiple countries their ids are stored in `selectedOptions` and displayed in this binding

```
<p data-bind="text:SelectedOptionText"></p>
```

this all works well but i want to display comma seperated text instead of ids like `United States , Canada` etc. How can i do that.
I have tried this

```
self.SelectedOptionText     =   ko.computed(function(){
    var selectedItems = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.List(),function(item){
        if(in_array(item.Value,self.SelectedOptions())){
            return item.Description
        }
    })

    return selectedItems.join(',')          
})
```

But it always returns object instead of `Description`.Also if the array is large it slow down on browser.
Note : in_array is a utility taken from [here](http://phpjs.org/functions/in_array/) phpjs.org.

Comment: @nemesv can you answer this.

Comment: This is not how the notification works on SO. (see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work) You can only only ping other users with `@...` if they have answered or commented on a particular question. Commenting "@nemesv can you answer this." on a newly created question won't directly notify me. Altough it can be that I will have a look on the question anyway :)

Comment: thanks i never knew that i will keep the thing in mind. Luckily you visited the question and answered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ko.utils.arrayFilter` as the name implies only filters your items it does not transform them.

You need a separate `ko.utils.arrayMap` where you get the `Description` of each item what you can now join together:

```
self.SelectedOptionText = ko.computed(function () {
    var selectedItems = ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.List(), function (item) {
        return in_array(item.Value, self.SelectedOptions());
    });
    var selectedDescriptions = ko.utils.arrayMap(selectedItems, function (item) {
        return item.Description;
    });
    return selectedDescriptions.join(',');
})
```

Note: you have also misused the `in_array` in your `ko.utils.arrayFilter` because in the callback you need to return `true` for an element if you want to include so you can just return the result of the `in_array` call.

Demo [JFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EBm5M/).

Or you can do the same lookup and mapping in one `ko.utils.arrayForEach` call:

```
self.SelectedOptionText = ko.computed(function () {
    var selectedDescriptions = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.List(), function (item) {
        if (in_array(item.Value, self.SelectedOptions()))
            selectedDescriptions.push(item.Description);
    });
    return selectedDescriptions.join(',');
})
```

Demo [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d73Fn/).